# What is the "to." domain name, and why does "http://to." work?

Tags: dns

While looking at a list of shortest domain names, I came along the domain name [to./](http://to./).

If I go to http://to./, I get the default Apache "It works!" page.

So, how does this domain name work? How does it consist of just the tld, with no name?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"to" is the [Top-Level Domain (TLD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) for the country of Tonga, just as "uk" is for the United Kingdom.

The trailing dot is valid - and is actually [the canonical correct or "absolute" form](http://www.dns-sd.org/trailingdotsindomainnames.html).

> It's a little-known fact, *but fully-qualified (unambiguous) DNS domain names have a dot at the end*.
>
> People running DNS servers usually know this (if you miss the trailing dots out, your DNS configuration is unlikely to work) but the general public usually doesn't. *A domain name that doesn't have a dot at the end is not fully-qualified and is potentially ambiguous.* This was documented in the DNS specification, RFC 1034, way back in 1987:

From [RFC 1034](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt):

> Since *a complete domain name ends with the root label*, this leads to a
>   printed form which ends in a dot.  We use this property to distinguish between:
>
> - a character string which represents a complete domain name
>      (often called "absolute").  For example, "poneria.ISI.EDU."
> - a character string that represents the starting labels of a
>      domain name which is incomplete, and should be completed by
>      local software using knowledge of the local domain (often
>      called "relative").  For example, "poneria" used in the
>      ISI.EDU domain.

Thus 'to.' is the absolute domain name for the 'to' TLD. The domain name is simply used to resolve (IP) addresses and, if resolved, can quite happily point to a web server.

Most TLDs to not resolve to an address - but there is no technical restriction on this.